# Combining RSelenium with Looping in R to add iterative value entries in web elements

Tags: r, loops, rselenium

I hope I can get some help with this problem:

I am using RSelenium to download records from a site, where I can download only in batches of 500. I have a very large amount of records to download so it would be great if I could make a loop that would look something like this pseudocode

```
# step one
navigate to website
# step two
find and click on the webelement 'from'
# step three
enter value 1 in the 'from' element and 500 in the 'to' element (this uses the tab key to move from 'from' to 'to')
# step four
initiate file extraction sequence
# step five
clear the 'from' and 'to' boxes OR renavigate to page
#step six
repeat as above but with value 501 in the 'from' element and 1000 in the 'to' element and extract those files
# step seven
repeat to n
```

Here is the actual code which I would like to add the loop in:

```
# this navigates to the website of interest.
remdr$navigate("somewebsite")

# here, my code clicks on the web element of interest
webElem4 <- remdr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#markFrom") #selects the element for the first number
webElem4$clickElement() # clicks on that element

# this enters the values for the records to be downloaded. In this case 1 - 500
webElem4$sendKeysToElement(list("001", key = "tab", "500")) # enters numbers into elements

# this is the sequence of clicks to download the data
webElem2 <- remdr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#exportTypeName") # selects the type of file to export
webElem2$clickElement() # clicks on selectien
webElem3 <- remdr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#exportButton") # exports selection
webElem3$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have now solved this using the below code

```
or (i in 0:99){
  # clear out elements
  webElem2 <- remdr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#markFrom") #selects the element for the first number
  webElem2$clearElement()
  webElem3 <- remdr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#markTo") #selects the element for the first number
  webElem3$clearElement()
  
  # here, my code clicks on the web element of interest
  webElem4 <- remdr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#markFrom") #selects the element for the first number
  webElem4$clickElement() # clicks on that element
  
  # this enters the values for the records to be downloaded. In this case 1 - 500
  webElem4$sendKeysToElement(list(paste(i*500+1), key = "tab", paste(i*500+1+500-1))) # enters numbers into elements
  
  # this is the sequence of clicks to download the data
  webElem5 <- remdr$findElement(using = "css selector", "button.quickOutputOther") # selects the type of file to export
  webElem5$clickElement() # clicks on selection
  webElem6 <- remdr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#exportButton") # exports selection
  webElem6$clickElement()
}
```